# Guitar tab plugin (jTab) should be active only in questions tagged [guitar]

Tags: feature-request, status-review, jtab, lilypond

I see that the **jTab** guitar tab plugin has been introduced at music.se now as it was on guitars.se, which I think is brilliant. But it should perhaps be only applied for questions tagged [guitar]. I just posted an answer to a [Harmonica question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/how-can-i-learn-48-holes-tremolo-harmonica/3260#3260), where I needed applied note names in a monospace font, and was converted to guitar tabs when I added. I had to simulate the spacing to get it work without code section.

Example of jTab kicking in, although I don't want it to be:

```
C    D    E    F    G    A    B    C  
out  in   out  in   out  in   in   out
```

Instead I had to do some hacking using the block quote format, and add some `&nbsp;` to align the spacing to an approximate:

> C   -  D -  E -  F -  G -  A -  B -  C
>     out in  out in  out  in  in  out

On StackOverflow, the programming language to use for code coloring is based on the language specified in the question tag ([C++], [C#] etc. use C encoding. [VB6], [VB.NET] etc. use VB encoding and so forth).

Comment: Another solution could be a different notation for jTab separate from the one for code.

Comment: +1: Great idea! Clearly we need better support for jTab in the first place (there's no autorendering), but this would certainly alleviate some headaches.

Comment: I'm adding the [tag:bug] tag to this since it wreaks absolute havok on Lilypond-related posts.

Comment: Agreed with this.  And when it activates it's really unclear what's happening.

Comment: @BenAlpert: I'm not sure I agree that jTab should not be in code section. Related to music, this is the perfect use of the *code* concept. What's missing is the concept of separating different "languages". I would also like the possibility to notate any form of music, which is [another important request](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/564/249).

Comment: Fast forward to now, looks like the jTab plugin is also enabled on meta...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A temporary workaround I've found is to use HTML `<pre></pre>` (preformatted text) tags around stuff that would otherwise be malinterpreted by jTab.

**EDIT:**

Lilypond makes great use of `<<` and `>>` symbols. These will get screwed up by `<pre>` tags unless you encode them as `&lt;&lt;` and `&gt;&gt;` respectively. Groan.

Comment: It'd be nice if <pre> would eat an initial newline.

Comment: That's HTML spec; pretty sure we can't/shouldn't change it.

Comment: That's true, but AIUI we *could* create a CSS `div` class that would work the same as `<pre>` but with this extra feature. Quite probably not worth the effort, but *possible* IMO.

Comment: Is there any news regarding this? We should make JTab optional (or remove it, no one ever uses it). I created a new meta post to discuss it.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is still struggling with this 5 years later (as I have been), I used inline ticks.

My problem: I wanted chords to appear thus, with the notes spelled out:

`C Dm Em etc...`

`C D E ...`
`E F G ...`
`G A B ...`

However when using pre-formatting (four spaces before text) I obtained the jTab chords, so instead I used inline ticks with line breaks

```
`chord name here`
`Chord notes`
```

which stopped the automatic jTab rendering.

Comment: You can also use the pre tags `<pre> </pre>`