# code block (lilypond) rendering

Tags: feature-request, bug, lilypond

When I open this page:

[How can I force LilyPond to repeat a chord symbol (relates to alternate endings)?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10959/how-can-i-force-lilypond-to-repeat-a-chord-symbol-relates-to-alternate-endings/10961#10961)

(using firefox),

the correct code blocks (question and answer) flash up for a fraction of a second and then disappear, leaving a grey block.

I suspect that this has something to do with the jTab support for
code blocks.

Trying to put the code in a `<pre></pre>` wrapper didn't work for me;
I believe that it has to do with the use of `<<` and `>>` constructs (or maybe other special characters) in lilypond source.

Being able to correctly support lilypond syntax as code blocks will greatly
improve questions about this software.

This question is related to [Guitar tab plugin (jTab) should be active only in questions tagged [guitar]](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/guitar-tab-plugin-jtab-should-be-active-only-in-questions-tagged-guitar)
if the problem is with the application of the jTab parser.

Comment: I've fixed the issue with those specific posts by converting the symbols to their HTML code versions and then using a `<pre>` block.

Comment: @MatthewRead could you answer and indicate what the relevant codes are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weird. When I saw that I reformatted both the question and answer, and they looked fine in Safari with just the four-space indent. That really deserves a fix.