# Size and format of images

Tags: support

I asked a question about notation and someone suggested that I submit an image. In what format and size should it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Exchange copes very well with all the popular formats, so if you submit as a gif, jpg or png they should show up just fine.

Also, by default, images will be resized to fit. That said, you can select a couple of options once imgur has uploaded your picture to shrink it down if you prefer a smaller image.

For guitar tablature, we have jTab [functionality](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/240/104) and for standard notation we have [abcjs](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2782/104) as well.

If you get the size wrong, or something messes up, don't worry - regular community members will edit to sort it out.