# Can the idiotic jTab thing just cease to exist please

Tags: support, jtab

Stop the madness. What kind of a campaign is needed to get the idiotic formatter to just stop formatting PRE-FORMATTED TEXT.

```
This is pre-formatted text
```

[image: pre-formatted text]

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid jTab by using html <pre></pre> tags. It is admittedly clumsy and frustrating. I think it would be good to have some way of declaring that a block uses jTab or Abc and default to text otherwise.

Comment: Yes, temporary workaround for 8 years and counting https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/guitar-tab-plugin-jtab-should-be-active-only-in-questions-tagged-guitar/244#244